# Error Message Remix "Allowance too low" Token Compilment Failed

Tags: solidity, remix

```
   function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(from) >= value, "balance too low")
        **require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, "allowance too low");**
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[from] -= value;
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
   }
```

I always get this error message like seen in the picture:

[image]

Due to that error I can't compile the token.

Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just missed the ";" :)

Change

```
        function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) { 
        require(balanceOf(from) >= value, "balance too low") 
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, "allowance too low"); 
        balances[to] += value; balances[from] -= value; 
        emit Transfer(from, to, value); return true;
    }
```

to

```
        function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) { 
        require(balanceOf(from) >= value, "balance too low");
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, "allowance too low"); 
        balances[to] += value; balances[from] -= value; 
        emit Transfer(from, to, value); return true;
}
```